# Exporting module - ES6 & TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

In python, we import names from other modules, without exporting those names.

---

In the below code from ES6,

```
// exports a function declared earlier
export { myFunction };
```

In TypeScript & ES6, Why to export a *name* to import it from other module? How *name* without `export` qualifier different from a *name* with `export` qualifier?

Comment: Python is generally more liberal with encapsulation as a general design philosophy so there's no need to specify what a module exposes.

Answer (score 2):

Think of ES2015 modules as a language-level extension of the revealing module pattern. You normally don't want to expose *everything* in a module to the outside world, so you choose what to `export` on your own by prefixing it with the `export` keyword:

```
export function myFunction() {
  doMagic();
}
```

And someone importing from that file will be able to `import { myFunction } from './module'`. If you don't `export` your function, it will not be available to import.

Comment: OK, i need to export something to import it